# How to fill array with strings which can contain multiple lines in Bash?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm having a variable with multiple strings, which can contain multiple lines:

```
var="foo 'bar baz' 'lorem
ipsum'"
```

I need all of them as array elements, so my idea was to use `xargs -n1` to read every quoted or unquoted string into separate array elements:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(xargs -n1 <<< "$(echo "$var")" )
```

But this causes this error:

```
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

Finally the only idea I had, was to replace the line feed against a carriage return and restore it afterwards:

```
# fill array                                  preserve line feed (dirty)
mapfile -t arr < <(xargs -n1 <<< "$(echo "$var" | tr '\n' '\r')" )

# restore line feed
for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ )); do
  arr[i]=$(echo "${arr[$i]}" | tr '\r' '\n')
done
```

It works:

```
# for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ )); do echo "index: $i, value: ${arr[$i]}"; done
index: 0, value: foo
index: 1, value: bar baz
index: 2, value: lorem
ipsum
```

But only as long the input variable does not contain a carriage return.

I assume I need `xargs` output every result delimited by a null byte and import with `mapfile`'s `-d ''`, but it seems `xargs` is missing a `print0` option (`tr '\n' '\0'` would manipulate the multi-line string itself).

Comment: how is the initial variable (`var`) populated? do you have any control over how `var` is populated (ie, can you change the structure of `var`)?

Comment: The easiest way is `eval arr=("$var")` but it is very dangerous if the variable `var` can contain strings like `$(...)`

Comment: Also see [Convert a string into an array with bash, honoring quotes for grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37372225/4154375).

Comment: *" it seems xargs is missing a print0"*.. `man xargs`. The first option is `-0, --null` which is often matched with `print0` for null terminated input/output from `find`. Good luck.

Comment: Some other previous Q/A that look relevant: ["Reading quoted/escaped arguments correctly from a string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string) and ["Get bash to respect quotes when word splitting subshell output"](https://superuser.com/questions/1529226/get-bash-to-respect-quotes-when-word-splitting-subshell-output).

Comment: @shellter `-0` is only relevant for the input, not the output.
@markp-fuso I have no control about `var`, but if it helps. you can manipulate `var`, before making further steps.
@M.NejatAydin No thanks ^^
@pjh I'm already using a technique to parse quoted strings/substrings. The question is how to parse a substring which contains line breaks

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your comment closely enough. Now I'm reading that last paragraph to say you would like a `0` for the last char of a multiline string?

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates a way to do it by using Bash regular expressions to extract parts from the string:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

var="foo 'bar baz' 'lorem
ipsum'"

leadspace_rx='^[[:space:]]+(.*)$'
bare_rx="^([^'[:space:]]+)(.*)\$"
quoted_rx="^'([^']*)'(.*)\$"

arr=()
while [[ -n $var ]]; do
    if [[ $var =~ $leadspace_rx ]]; then
        var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    elif [[ $var =~ $bare_rx ]]; then
        arr+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
        var=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    elif [[ $var =~ $quoted_rx ]]; then
        arr+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
        var=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    else
        printf 'ERROR: Cannot handle: %s\n' "$var" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

declare -p arr
```

- The output is `declare -a arr=([0]="foo" [1]="bar baz" [2]=$'lorem\nipsum')`
- The code for splitting up a string could easily be encapsulated in a function if you think this idea is worth pursuing.
- The current code does things that you might not expect.  For instance, the string `a'b'c` is converted to the array `(a b c)`.  If you can provide a more precise specification for the format of input strings I'll see if the code can be modified to handle it.